# Using php function in html

Tags: php, html, function

Need some help guys I'm working on a order form using Php, I have the function correct because it works fine when I just echo it out. 
But I can't figure out how to call the function correctly into my div on my table. I want to be able to display the result of quantity times price. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?
/*
print_r($_POST)
*/

$firstName =  $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["emailAddress"];

$appleQuantity = $_POST["apple"];
$baconQuantity = $_POST["bacon"];
$breadQuantity = $_POST["bread"];
$cheeseQuantity = $_POST["cheese"];
$eggsQuantity = $_POST["eggs"];
$hamQuantity = $_POST["ham"];
$milkQuantity = $_POST["milk"];

$priceApples = 10;
$priceBacon = 2.5;
$priceBread = 5;
$priceCheese = 5;
$priceEggs = 3.6;
$priceHame = 6;
$priceMilk = 4;



 function subTotal($incomingQuantity , $incomingPrice)
{
 return $incomingQuantity * $incomingPrice;
}

?>



 <div align="center"><? subTotal($incomingQuantity , $incomingPrice ) ?></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to print the return value of the function with `echo` ? Just a idea...

Comment: All this talk about food has given me the munchies.

Comment: `<?= subTotal($incomingQuantity , $incomingPrice ) ?>` simple as adding an equal sign; assuming short tags are set/on. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't do any output, it's just RETURNING the value. You need an echo in there somewhere.

e.g.

```
<div><?php echo subTotal(...) ?></div>
```

or

```
function subTotal(...) {
   echo $result
}
```

Comment: and to be safe with the compiler, add a semicolon after each command.

Comment: Could've just added an `=` - `<?= subTotal($incomingQuantity , $incomingPrice ) ?>` - Well, assuming short tags are set ;-)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have to display output in a textbox inside a div as

```
<input type="text" id="myText" >
```

then your function can be

```
function subTotal($incomingQuantity , $incomingPrice)
{
 var result = $incomingQuantity * $incomingPrice;

document.getElementById("myText").value = result;
}
```